# Get the envelope of a signal in Matlab

Tags: matlab, processing, envelope

I don't know how to compute the envelope of a signal. I've already seen the mathwork solutions [firstSolution](http://es.mathworks.com/help/dsp/examples/envelope-detection.html) [secondSolution](http://es.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/envelope-extraction-using-the-analytic-signal.html) but they does not work in the signal I'm working with.

This signal provides from a pressure sensor and it's sampled at a frequency of 1kHz and it has 100000 samples.

I've read that with the hilbert transform I could get the envelope by doing abs(hilbert(data)) being data the values of the signal2.txt but it has not work. I've also tried with taking the absolute value of the analytic signal but it has not work either.

The solution I've tried is to find the peaks and put them together linearly but it does not work properly because I want a continuous and derivable function as result so as I need to derivate it.

I hope you knew the solution to my problem. :)

Comment: Post your code with an example that illustrates your problem. If that helps, when I need to do envelope detection I take`abs` of the signal and then apply a lowpass filter (see `butter`) with cutoff frequency above the envelope variations and below the carrier frequency

Comment: If `abs(hilbert(data))` produces an error, then your data is not of a common format. Can you plot the data using MATLAB, e.g. with `plot(data)`? What are the errors you get? If you import them from a .txt file, how did you implement that step (maybe the error lies there)?